# How to find maximum of function outputs with multipe inputs in one function?

Tags: function, haskell

I want a function maxfunct, with input f (a function) and input n (int), that computes all outputs of function f with inputs 0 to n, and checks for the max value of the output.

I am quite new to haskell, what I tried is something like that:

```hs
maxfunct f n
  | n < 0 = 0
  | otherwise = maximum [k | k <- [\(f, x)-> f x], x<- [0..n]]
```

Idea is that I store every output of f in a list, and check for the maximum in this list.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: What, in your opinion, does `k <- [\(f, x)-> f x]` mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close. First, let's note the type of the function we're trying to write. Starting with the type, in addition to helping you get a better feel for the function, also lets the compiler give us better error messages. It looks like you're expecting a function and an integer. The result of the function should be compatible with `maximum` (i.e. should satisfy `Ord`) and also needs to have a reasonable "zero" value (so we'll just say it needs `Num`, for simplicity's sake; in reality, we might consider using `Bounded` or `Monoid` or something, depending on your needs, but `Num` will suffice for now).

So here's what I propose as the type signature.

```
maxfunct :: (Num a, Ord a) => (Int -> a) -> Int -> a
```

Technically, we could generalize a bit more and make the `Int` a type argument as well (requires `Num`, `Enum`, and `Ord`), but that's probably overkill. Now, let's look at your implementation.

```
maxfunct f n
  | n < 0 = 0
  | otherwise = maximum [k | k <- [\(f, x)-> f x], x<- [0..n]]
```

Not bad. The first case is definitely good. But I think you may have gotten a bit confused in the list comprehension syntax. What we *want* to say is: take every value from `0` to `n`, apply `f` to it, and then maximize.

```
maxfunct :: (Num a, Ord a) => (Int -> a) -> Int -> a
maxfunct f n
  | n < 0 = 0
  | otherwise = maximum [f x | x <- [0..n]]
```

and there you have it. For what it's worth, you can also do this with `map` pretty easily.

```
maxfunct :: (Num a, Ord a) => (Int -> a) -> Int -> a
maxfunct f n
  | n < 0 = 0
  | otherwise = maximum $ map f [0..n]
```

It's just a matter of which you find more easily readable. I'm a `map` / `filter` guy myself, but lots of folks prefer list comprehensions, so to each his own.